# Haskell couldn't match expected type [char] with actual type IO

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I just started learning Haskell, and i'm on stuck on this error among a bunch of others

i'm trying to print all the characters in the char list recursively with this code

```
printall :: [Char] -> [Char]
printall "" = ""
printall (i:is) = if is /= "" then print i else printall is

main = printall "hello world"
```

but i get this error could anyone help me?

```
intro.hs:14:36: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type
‘IO ()’
• In the expression: print i
  In the expression: if is /= "" then print i else printa
ll is
  In an equation for ‘printall’:
      printall (i : is) = if is /= "" then print i else p
 rintall is

intro.hs:16:1: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘IO t0’ with actual type ‘
[Char]’
```

Comment: Please justify the type signature you gave to `printall`, or perhaps just remove it and see what happens.

Comment: @n.m. i guess the type signature is redundant, the same error persists without it

Comment: Great, now you have this `printall "" = ""` line, and also `printall (i:is)` line. The latter has `print i` in the `then` branch and `printall is` in the `else` branch, The types of the two expressions ought to be the same. Are they?

Comment: If you want your function to return a string without doing any IO, you use `[Char]` as the return type. If you want it to do IO and not return a value, use `IO ()` as a return type. If you want to both return a string and do IO then use `IO [Char]` as a return type. Whatever type you choose, you must be coherent with it in all the branches of your code.

Comment: @n.m. ohh you just reminded me in haskell each expression must the same type, 'print i' would return a single char whereas 'printall is' will return a list of char, the two types are not interchangeable. i'm i on the right lines?

Comment: No, `print t` would not return a `Char`. It's an IO function. You can check its type by entering `:t print` at ghci prompt.

Comment: @n.m. true, now i changed the code to `return i` it works but only returns the first index as the recursive call is never met, how do i fix that?

Comment: In order to print a list you need to print a head **and** print a tail. You are never doing the "and" part.

Comment: @n.m. oh thanks thats done the trick, i would totally pay you to be my mentor but im a broke student hahaha

Answer (score 3):

As you said in a comment above, each branch of the if clause should have the same type, indeed.

Also, `main` function must always have `IO a` type, for some `a`, which is usually `()`. This means that the type signature for `printall` should be:

```
printall :: [Char] -> IO ()
```

which is the same as:

```
printall :: String -> IO ()
```

Comment: `main` does not need to be `IO ()`. It only has to be `IO t` for some `t`. `main = return 0` will compile fine.

Answer (score 0):

`print` type is `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`

but your `printall` type is `printall :: [Char] -> [Char]`, assume it is what you want.

The expression `if x then y else z` need the same type for `y` and `z`